# function extension for class in another class

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I want to make a function extension for class inside of another class (for `String` in `ModelAndView`, not for inner), but have not found a way to do this without class inheritance. Is it possible at all?

Example of class extension:

```
class MyModelAndView : ModelAndView() {
   infix fun String.to(value: Any?) {
      addObject(this, value)
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without class extension"?

Comment: sory, I mean inheritance

Comment: That still isn't clear.  Can you show an example of what isn't working?

Comment: I want kind of this : infix fun ModelAndView.String.to(value: Any?){//...}

Comment: Why do you want that?  An extension defined *inside* a class is only usable  inside that class.  So what would be the purpose of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create member extension functions in classes, but these extensions can only be accessed in the class':

```
class X {
    fun String.ext() = println("extension on $this called")
    fun useExtension() {
        val text: String = "myText"
        text.ext()
    }
}
```

You can only use this extension inside the class, as shown in `useExtension`, and also in the context of that class, which for instance can be used in `with`:

```
with(x) { "abc".ext() }
```

It's not recommended to do this, although it makes sense when writing DSLs for example.

Comment: You can access it outside the class by doing `with(x) { "abc".ext() }`.

Comment: But only in the context of the class, this works because it's a lambda with receiver `X`

Comment: What do you mean with "only in the context of the class"? If a class defines a public extension method, you can access it anywhere you have an object of that class using that `with`-trick.

Comment: `with` creates that context.

Comment: @ s1m0nw1 I know you know how this whole thing works, but I have to agree with @marstran your wording is misleading: "cannot use outside the class" and "need an object of the class in the context to use" are very different things.